# Blank page when using file_get_contents() on a website with port 8080

Tags: php, html, web, file-get-contents

When I run the following code on one of my websites:

```
    <?php
    $thing = file_get_contents("http://mywebsite.com:8080/Public");
    echo($thing);
    ?>
```

It returns expected result, the contents of http://mywebsite.com:8080/Public

But when I run it on my other website (**hosted on by a different company**), it does not display anything. No errors and not the contents of http://mywebsite:8080/Public. However, if I run the following code:

```
    <?php
    $thing = file_get_contents("http://somerandomwebsite.com");
    echo($thing);
    ?>
```

It returns the contents of somerandomwebsite.com. Is there a reason why it works on one of the websites and not the other? Why can it only fetch the contents of the file if the port is 80?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`file_get_contents` fails because it cannot retrieve the content at hand. Most likely, a simplistic firewall is blocking all traffic to non-80 ports. You'll have to use port 80 to avoid these simplistic firewalls.

The failure to download the resource makes php emit a warning. Most likely, warnings are not displayed on the production server. Check the server's log and the [`display_errors`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors) and [`error_reporting`](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting) configurations.

Comment: Is there a different way to bypass the firewall, because there is no way to modify the port to which I need to connect

Comment: @user1036238 You can set up a proxy, can't you? Just pick a domain and proxy all HTTP requests (on port 80) to that domain to the correct domain at port 8080. Other than that, you can try using HTTPS, but that's unlikely to work. Why do you think there is no way to modify the port to which you need to connect?

Comment: The website I'm trying to connect to is a webserver run by McMyAdmin, a minecraft server wrapper. So setting up a proxy isn't really an option. I would just prefer to use 8080 instead of 80 but if it is the only option, I can change it

Comment: @user1036238 I don't get why setting up a proxy is not an option. If you can spare an IP, you can always just redirect all connections at the TCP level to the 8080 port, no matter whether they're HTTP or not.

Comment: I don't have any spare IPs. I just changed the port to 80

Answer (score 1):

Check with your hosting provider if it allows PHP to make external requests. Some shared hosting providers disable that.

Comment: I don't think that is the case, because the request is working with somerandomwebsite.com, just not http://mywebsite.com:8080/Public

Comment: The same principle applies, sometimes some ports are blocked for security reasons. For example, Hosgator blocks 8080.